# How to configure Oracle19c to use case-insensitive passwords?

Tags: linux, oracle

How can I make Oracle19c accept case-insensitive passwords? That is, I want "mypAsswOrd" password to serve as "MyPaSsWoRd" or "MyPassword".

Comment: You do realize, of course (don't you?) that this actually _weakens_ password security.  There is a reason that oracle made case_INsensitive passwords no longer the default.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: this info widely available on the web

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "sec_case_sensitive_logon" parameter

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON.html

but be aware, there will come a point in time *soon* that the Oracle database will *only* allow case sensitive password. We are phasing out the option to have them be otherwise.

Comment: Turning off case sensitivity in Oracle19c disabled access to ALL accounts for me. Although it is not mentioned in the linked documentation, it seems that Oracle has already disabled that option in a way that breaks access completely.

Comment: The culprit is yet another parameter. `Setting SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON to FALSE when SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER is set to 12 or 12a causes all accounts to become inaccessible`. Setting it to 11 apparently works. See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-2C63433B-1C93-4DFE-B2B9-F63E8C3EEC1F